# Why doesn't elasticsearch OOM show in cluster logs?

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm

I have an elasticsearch cluster with 9 data nodes (9 x 25G RAM / 12G Heap), and am automating periodic queries with elastic-recheck which in turn uses pyelasticsearch to query the cluster. I'm using elasticsearch version 1.7.5 and pyelasticsearch version 0.7.1.

Recently the queries started returning `pyelasticsearch.exceptions.ElasticHttpError: (500, u'OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]')` but there is no sign of this error in any of the data nodes' logs. At first I thought "oh, I've outgrown my cluster size" and added the 9th data node. But then when the 500s didn't stop I realized that the data nodes were not logging the memory errors. The last time this happened, there would be logs of the error both on the cluster master and on the specific node that ran out of heap. Adding the 8th node resolved that issue.

So my question is: why would the client receive this error but none of the data nodes log an error about running out of heap? And as a follow-up: how can I find what the underlying issue is?

Comment: Probably your client ran OOM?

Comment: I don't think it was a client OOM, the `(500, u'OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]')` came from the http response which means that the string was generated on the remote side.

Comment: So far I haven't seen an ES node going OOM and not logging that error.